# Flag as spam/offensive links broken in 10k tools area?

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, flags

The links are currently set as simply '#', and nothing occurs (in terms of the relevant flag being incremented) if you click the links, so I presume they'be been disabled for a reason.

That said, thought it best to open a question just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is entirely my fault ; in moving some code for a new moderator-only feature, I obviously dropped some necessary js for non-moderators; will fix this evening.

(fixed in next build)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but probably the link has a JavaScript onclick handler that posts the vote when you click on it.

Comment: Thought that myself initially, but there's no explicit 'onclick="..."' handler in there and nothing seems to be happen (in terms of incrementing the flag's count) when you click the links. (Tried it on multiple browsers.)

Comment: @middaparka It definitely (used to) work. And no, the `onclick` attribute is definitely *not* the best way to check for an event handler attached to an element, not when we're talking about unobtrusive JavaScript

Comment: @Yi Yup, I didn't fancy delving into the JavaScript to hunt for an event handler. (For I am very lazy.) It's certainly worked in the past though.