# Dismiss flag in 10K tools error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools

On https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged, clicking the `Dismiss` button produces "An unknown error occurred". Is this a bug?

Comment: Have to wonder if this is related to the fix for the [Flag as spam/offensive links broken in 10k tools area?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77746/flag-as-spam-offensive-links-broken-in-10k-tools-area) issue. :-)

Comment: This will be fixed next build

Comment: @MarcGravell The button's gone, but the help section is still there

Comment: @Yi will clean up, ta. Do you mean the "dismiss" one? That is new - probably just missing a mod-check

Comment: @Marc: Bug's back again?  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77923/dismiss-flag-in-10k-tools-error-message/91979#91979

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's a bug that the dismiss link is showing up for non-moderators:
[I see a link to dismiss a flag when I don't have the privileges to do so](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/i-see-a-link-to-dismiss-a-flag-when-i-dont-have-the-privileges-to-do-so)

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting here since it appears the bug has been reintroduced again.  I had the page in view when I was reviewing a post flagged as spam (contemplating if I should also flag it) and noticed it was deleted by a mod anyway.  I then refreshed the page and saw this:

[image: delete and dismiss?]

It wasn't like that before refreshing.  Last time I checked, I am not a mod.  I'm seeing this too on other browsers clearing the cache.  Was the flag reason alone intended to be added?  (I hope so)  If so, too much information.

Comment: @Jeff - booting up to fix that

Comment: @Marc: Ok.  I'll be here if you need any more information.  (it is still in view as of now)

Comment: @Jeff - it is building and deploying as I type. Let me know if it goes away?

Comment: @Marc, I too am noticing this.  Very neato to see the flag reasons though.  Would be nice if that was always visible to 10k+ users.

Comment: @Kirk - you shouldn't be noticing it any more; can you ACK/NACK?

Comment: @Marc: All gone... all of it.  :]

Comment: @Marc, yep, all gone.

Comment: @Marc: Quick question for you.  Prior to this happening, hovering over the flag counts used to show what the flag type was but not any actual messages.  e.g., rude/offensive, chatty, etc.  At least I know this was true for the red ones but I don't remember if it was the same for blue.  Now hovering over them shows nothing (the blue ones at least).  Should we have been able to see the flag types in the first place?

Comment: @Jeff - yes, that is fine.