# What does "dismiss" mean in tools/flagged?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, 10k-tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dismiss flag in 10K tools error message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77923/dismiss-flag-in-10k-tools-error-message)

As a new-ish 10ker, I ventured over to https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged and I saw a bunch of entries with the only option for each being a link to "dismiss". There is no tooltip on this link, nor sufficient information on this page for me to know how to help.

- I expected both 'thumbs up' ("make it so") and 'thumbs down' (I disagree) options. Why don't either/both of those exist? (Is my rep insufficient?)
- I don't know which (if either) this link is. Is it "please mark this as 'read' and don't show it to me again"?
- Where are the docs on moderation? Is it just searching through meta posts?
- (the actual question/feature request) Can you please add a tooltip to these links that makes clear what the action will do?

Comment: @badp Thanks for 10k-vs-mod distinction. My question really is a feature-request, though, as adding knowledge for me is less important than making this obvious for all future 10ks.

Comment: This will be fixed next build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/i-see-a-link-to-dismiss-a-flag-when-i-dont-have-the-privileges-to-do-so) on meta programmers.

As a 10K user you shouldn't be seeing the "dismiss" link.

If you click it you get an error.

The link is for moderators to remove the flag from the post.